# how to trigger a vpn connection in F5 Access from other app in android

Tags: java, android, vpn, f5

I am implementing a company level app, so all the api calling needs the device to connect to the company network first, otherwise it would not work. we have a F5Access app installed on the device with a vpn configuration for connecting to company network. so is there a way to trigger the connection in F5 when my app opens? or if there is other workaround.  thanks very much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: please show your vpn connection code here..

Comment: i dont have any connection code, I am asking if there is a way to trigger a vpn connection. no idea how to do it.